# Need to add new file format to upload from front end and add it to cart on Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, custom-options, addtocart, file-upload

I have Magento 1.8. I added the custom options in the product to upload the file. That product will work like configurable product and will get added to the cart. Now i want to have the `.stl` file format to also get uploaded but it's not working.

Comment: Did I get you correctly, you want a shop user to upload files via a custom option? What kind of error do you get when you try to upload a `.stl` file?

Comment: Yes great you got me exactly:)

Comment: It simply does not shows that file on the cart page as i have the option/condition to show that.

Comment: Please check your server error and and Magento log files - there most likely will be a hint about what is going on while you try to add a file. If your're running your shop on an unix-based system you can for example run `tail -f var/log/system.log` on CLI to get a live feed of the log while you navigate in your shop.

Comment: There is no such error in the system log file. Also if I upload .xls , png , jpeg , gif , txt all files are uploaded and are visible on the cart page.

Comment: The product got added to cart but only the file is missing or is the product it self also not added to cart? If so, did you check the servers error log as well? If you hit for example the `upload_max_filesize` this wont be tracked in any Magento log but in your server logs...

Comment: The products gets added with all other custom option values but only the file is missing.

Comment: I see - so this seems not to be a bit more tough one. You could, in order to eliminate some of the few remaining server-related issue check whether there might be some security software installed on the system that would identify that file as harmful (maybe even try to create an empty text file and rename it to "test.stl" and upload that one). Else you will have to start debugging from where Magento is adding products to cart which would be `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php::addAction()`

Comment: Can you help me to get that fixed..I checked that but have not find anything..